# call a function in utility class

Tags: c#, asp.net, utility-method

I have a function in a utility class

```
  namespace GUI.code
 {
   public class Utility
  {
     public string GetFileName(string grpID)
    {
        string filenameUNC = "\\\\" + "localhost" + "\\AgentShare\\";

        string realPath = GetPath(filenameUNC);

        return realPath;
    }
   }
  }
```

now i call this function from another page in the project like this:

```
new utility.GetCSFileName(ID);
```

why do i need to add new, why cant i call it like

```
GetCSFileName(ID);
```

when i have

```
     using GUI.code;
```

on top

if i remove new i get this error

> Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'copiunGUI.code.GUIUtility.GetCSFileName(string)

any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `Utility.GetFileName()` if you change the declaration to `public static string GetFileName(string grpID)`

`static` means that the member is shared among all *instances* of the `Utility` class. Remember, c# is an *object-oriented* language. Non-static members are called *instance* members, and must be called on a distinct instance of the class. Each time you call `new Utility()`, you are creating such an instance, and this is distinct from every other.

This is useful when each instance of a class needs to maintain information (state) internally. If, however, a particular member does not use state data -- it accepts parameters, does work, and optionally returns a result -- it can be declared static. Then you call it not from the instance variable but from the class name itself (in this case `Utility.GetFileName()`.

When all of the members of a class are `static`, you can add `static` to the class declaration itself. At that point, you would never be able to call `new Utility()`, which might be what you want in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark your method as static.

```
public class Utility
{
     public static string GetFileName(string grpID)
     {
            string filenameUNC = "\\\\" + "localhost" + "\\AgentShare\\";

            string realPath = GetPath(filenameUNC);

            return realPath;
     }
}
```

You will then be able to call your method with `Utility.GetFileName(...)`

Read more on static methods / classes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to mark your method (and possibly your class also) as static:

```
public static class Utility
{
   public static string GetFileName(string grpID)
   ...
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
string filename = Utility.GetFileName(ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the method static and you can use it without an instance of the class

eg

```
public static string GetFileName(string grpID)
```

usage:

```
Utility.GetCSFileName(ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have a new one, if you set up your method as a static method:

```
public static string GetFileName(string grpID)
{
 //your code here
}
```

Then you still have to call the Class name, but you don't have to instantiate it:

so instead of: 
    Utility util = new Utility();
    util.GetFileName("myString");

you can do:

```
Utility.GetFileName("myString");
```

And the reason you can't do just `GetFileName("myString")` is that you're not calling it from inside the class where it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

When a method is marked with the `static` keyword it means that you don't have to create a new instance of the object (using 'new') to call the method, as you intend.

One thing to watch out for is that if you mark a method as being static, it cannot call any non-static methods, only static ones. You also can't use any properties of the object that are non-static.

Answer (score 1):

the trick is to define method as static. This will do it:

```
 namespace GUI.code
 {
   public class Utility
  {
     public static string GetFileName(string grpID)
    {
        string filenameUNC = "\\\\" + "localhost" + "\\AgentShare\\";

        string realPath = GetPath(filenameUNC);

        return realPath;
    }
   }
  }
```

now you can write `utility.GetCSFileName(ID);`.
But you still have to mention class.